# can one function be overwritten by calling another?

Tags: python, function, local

Let's say you have functions `a` and `b`. Can you, by calling function `a`, replace function `b` with another function?

I know you can do `b=a(b)`, but can you change `b` with just doing `a(b)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions and methods are attributes of modules and classes respectively. So you can modify the required attribute to point to another function.

```
>>> __name__
'__main__'
>>> def a():
...     print 'a'
... 
>>> def b():
...     print 'b'
... 
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['__main__'].b = a
>>> b()
a
```

For a class:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def a(self):
...             print 'a'
...     def b(self):
...             print 'b'
... 
>>> A.b = A.a
>>> x = A()
>>> x.b()
a
```

And if you have a variable holding the name to replace, then use `setattr`, for example:

```
setattr(sys.modules['__main__'],'b',a)
setattr(A,'b',A.a)
```

Just replace the string ('b') with your variable.

Not sure why you would want to though? It will make for confusing code.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace the code object of `b` with another function's code:

```
>>> def b():
...    print 'b'
...
>>> def a():
...    print 'a'
...
>>> def c(f):
...    f.__code__ = a.__code__ # func_code instead of __code__ for py 2.5 and earlier
...
>>> c(b)
>>> b()
a
```

Although this is almost certainly a sign you're thinking of whatever problem you're trying to solve in the wrong way.

Comment: I was writing up the same thing, although I used `__code__` (more forward-compatible).  +1 for knowing it, but +10 for the comment that if this is the answer the question's gone off the rails.

Comment: oddly, `__code__` isn't on the Object Model page of the python docs (unlike the `__name__` and `__doc__` aliases), but seems to work back to python 2.6, so edited.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `global` to accomplish something like this.

```
>>> def a():
...     global b
...     def b():
...         print "New Function B"
>>> def b():
...     print "Function B"
...
...
>>> b()
Function B
>>> a()
>>> b()
New Function B
>>>
```

If you don't know which method you're replacing, you can use `function.func_code` to replace one function's code with another.

```
>>> def change(old_func, new_func):
...     old_func.func_code = new_func.func_code
...
>>> def a():
...     print "Function A"
...
>>> def b():
...     print "Function B"
...
>>> def c():
...     print "Function C"
...
>>>
>>> change(a, b)
>>> a()
Function B
>>> change(a, c)
>>> a()
Function C
>>>
```

Comment: What if I don't know I'm overwriting `b` beforehand?In other words, if I want to pass `b` as an argument to `a`.

Comment: I'm a bit stuck between choosing using `globals()` and `setattr(sys.modules[__name__],'b',a)`. Maybe because I don't understand globals() too well and think since there is `locals()` then it won't work everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are aiming for, but yes, you can do that:

```
>>> def a():
...     global b
...     b = a
...     return 'a'
... 
>>> def b():
...     return 'b'
... 
>>> b()
'b'
>>> a()
'a'
>>> b()
'a'
>>> def c(f):
```

> What if I don't know I'm overwriting b beforehand?In other words, if I want to pass b as an argument to a

```
>>> def c(f):
...     global b
...     b = f
...     return 'c'
... 
>>> def d():
...     return 'd'
... 
>>> b()
'a'
>>> c(d)
'c'
>>> b()
'd'
>>> c(a)
'c'
>>> b()
'a'
```

Comment: What if I don't know I'm overwriting `b` beforehand?In other words, if I want to pass `b` as an argument to `a`.

Comment: I extended my answer adding a function `c` which takes a function that can be used to replace `b`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily like this

```
def a(func):
    globals()[func] = c

def b():
    print('b')

def c():
    print('c')

a()
b()
>>> c
```